# Schwarz's lemma application on a composition of functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\Delta=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ |z| < 1\}$. Suppose that $F:\Delta\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and injective. Assume that $g: \Delta \to F(\Delta)$ is holomorphic and $g(0)=F(0)$. Prove that $|g'(0)|\leq |F'(0)|$ and that
>   $$g(D(0,r)) \subseteq F(D(0,r)), \ 0<r<1.$$

I proved the first part, I cannot prove the second part.
The function $F:\Delta \to F(\Delta)$ is bijective so it has an inverse, define $h(z) : \Delta \to \Delta : z \mapsto F^{-1}\circ g(z)$. $h$ is holomorphic and $h(0) = 0$, so we can apply Schwarz's lemma to $h$. This gives us that $|h'(0)|\leq 1$ and $|h(z)|\le|z|$ for $|z| < 1$. $|h'(0)| \leq 1 \implies |g'(0)|\leq |F'(0)|$.

I assume you would use $|h(z)|<|z|$ for $|z| < 1$ to prove the second part, but I'm unable to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $w \in g(D(0,r))$. Then $w = g(z)$ for some $z \in D(0,r)$ and
$$
 |F^{-1}(w)| = |F^{-1}(g(z))| = |h(z)| \le |z| < r 
$$
which means that $F^{-1}(w) \in D(0, r)$ or equivalently, $w \in F(D(0, r))$.